# Looking for the climate classification for a particular climate

Tags: climate, temperature, models, geography, precipitation

I'm looking for the climate classification among the many different climate classification systems covering my absolute favorite form of climate. If a classification for this doesn't exist, and you happen to know of some places with this form of climate, a few places would work great as well!

By the way, I'm asking this here as I haven't found any places like this yet, but I'm really hoping to!

Conditions:

- Snowy winters (1-5 m or 3-15 ft of snow) averaging between -5°C and 10°C (20°F to 50°F)
- Low-humidity summers averaging between 10°C and 35°C (50°F to 95°F)
- Decent amount of rain (but preferably not in winter), meaning no extended dry season
- Coastal, ideally along an ocean, but along a very large lake works too

With the exception of the last condition, which only makes sense if someone happens to have places in mind instead of climate classifications, I've looked into all of these with existing climate classification systems and struggled to find a category that really captures them all:

- **Holdridge life zones** put this somewhere between *boreal moist forest*, *boreal wet forest*, *cool temperature moist forest*, *cool temperate wet forest*, *warm temperature moist forest*, and *wet temperature wet forest* but don't really capture the summer-winter gradient very well
- **Trewartha climate classification** seems to have a few options that could cover this climate. *Cs*, *Do*, and *Dca* seem to fit best, with optional *ak*, *ao*, *bk*, or *bo* suffixes for the universal thermal scale
- **Köppen climate classification** puts this somewhere in *Cfa*, *Cfb*, *Csa*, *Dfa*, *Dfb*, *Dsa*, and *Dsb*, but again it doesn't seem like all the nuance is captured. It probably doesn't help that I'm the least familiar with this system, and after spending a solid half hour looking into the various classifications and their criteria I ended up with a list covering about a quarter of all possible classifications under this system

#### Edit

I was a little unclear in explaining the temperature ranges above. To clarify, I'm looking for *average* winter temperatures between around -5°C and 10°C, and *average* summer temperatures between around 10°C and 35°C. I didn't mean for those to be interpreted as absolute bounds on possible temperatures, which would be fairly difficult to find given the small winter range and large summer range. To prevent future misinterpretation, I've added the word *averaging* to the first two bullet points above.

Comment: I think it's easier if you give an exemplary location which has exactly this climate. Then it's easier to decide which climate this place has. Because if there's no place on earth with this climate, there's also no classification for it.

Comment: @Erik That's not necessarily true; some classification systems may allow for classifying combinations that happen not to exist on Earth, just by extending the logic of how the classification is constructed.

Comment: This sounds like a four season Shangri-La climate (i.e., it doesn't exist), especially with the small winter temperature range, lots of snow (5 meters is mountainous levels of snow), and the low humidity summers with plenty of rain.

Comment: this is a city that in theory could have the climate you look for https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/norway/kristiansand/climate the seawater will keep the temperature above freezing so very little snow will acumulate,so the summer is a fit but the winter will not be anywhere close to what you want.your climate is simply not possible to find.

Comment: @DavidHammen you're not the only one to misinterpret my ranges there, I think I could've been a lot more clear. I included the ranges to account for variation from city to city, not the climate range within a given city. Average yearly snowfall anywhere between 1 meter and 5 meters, typical winters *averaging* anywhere between -5°C and 10°C, low-humidity summers *averaging* anywhere between 10°C and 35°C. Sorry if I didn't see the potential for misinterpretation when I wrote up the question.

Comment: The question remains a bit unclear: Are those monthly average highs, or averages of the monthly average high and monthly average low? Ignoring that, Buffalo NY looks like a good match with the update -- except for the humidity. Low humidity in the summer almost inevitable means low precipitation. You're going to have to suffer a bit in the summer from high humidity if you want plantlife to remain green throughout the summer.

Comment: @DavidHammen Averages of the monthly average high and average low, for daytime at least. Does occasional rain require high humidity otherwise, or do there exist places that are rainy every few weeks but low-humidity otherwise?